# Is it haram to replace human figures with sprites or beans in games?

Tags: drawing, art

I am game developer.. I want to make a game where I want a player figure.. but as it is haram to make human figures and animate them .. can I somehow replace those human figures with something not so human looking ( no eyes or hair ) .. for example something that looks like can of pepsi and animate it .. or maybe something that looks like a human but with no face or no eyes and nose. is doing that haram ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There shouldn't be anything wrong with a game using beans or whatever.
The forbidding of painting humans and animals refers in first place to a strict interdiction to use paintings for worship or to show any alike behaviour to a statue. It has been extended to any drawings of humans or animals in Islam teaching because there is no hint in the ahadit referring to a case where it would be allowed to draw. But there is none that could be interpreted as general interdiction for computer animated games.